# Delete SFX file after extraction

Tags: batch-file, command-line, winrar

I created a SFX to extract some files. After the extraction, I need that the SFX file is deleted.
As far as I have seen, WinRar does not offer such option. So I thought to run some DOS command -prompt (like bat).

This is my code so far (not working):

```
SETUP=cmd /c del /f /q "file-to-delete"
```

It opens the cmd, flashes and then closes...

Someone with a similar problem: http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/34506-sfx-remove-file-after-extraction/

Comment: is your `SETUP=` a WinRar directive?  Ensure the full path to the file is included.

Comment: Yes, "SETUP=" is AN winrar diretive and it allows to run a specific program after the SFX automatic extraction, which can be "Setup.exe" or "Install.exe" or "script.bat", etc... the path is fine I just can't find the way to make it works

Comment: Your problem is that the SFX is still running, so if you try to delete it you're only going to end up with an Access Denied error.

Comment: Karan, that's not the case. Winrar have specicif directives to be used BEFORE, DURING or AFTER the exctraction process. In this case, the SETUP directive is excevuted at the ende (after SFX has finished). So there is no problem to delete the file. By the way, foxidrive has the exactly solution. Thank you by the way.

Comment: Hmm, wonder why `cmd` doesn't work but `cmd.exe` does (with or without the full path, former is what `%comspec%` contains). So all you had to do was change your code to `SETUP=cmd.exe /c del /f /q "name-of-sfx"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this works - include the accurate path to the file and see if it deletes it.  If it does then you can try relative paths.

```
SETUP="%comspec%" /c del "c:\program location\file-to-delete"
```

If that fails then include this command in a bat file located where the file is and then use the bat file to delete the SFX file, in the WinRar directive.

```
@echo off
del "file-to-delete"
```

Comment: PERFECT! "%comspec%" /c del "c:\program location\file-to-delete" made the trick. But how did you know?

Answer (score 0):

you must select the GUY mode of the SFX archive.
32 bit rar mode on 64 machine will not delete
64 bit rar on 64 will delete the file.

otherwise you can use powershell to delete a folder in the cmd.

```
powershell "rd -r \"%PROGRAMFILES%\company\folder\""
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution deletes the self-extracting (SFX) archive itself. The other solution appears to be deleting an extracted file.

1. Select **Default64.SFX** for the SFX module in the **Advanced SFX options** dialog, **Module** tab.
2. In the **Setup** tab add the following text with quotes: **"%comspec%" /c del "%sfxname%"**
3. In the **Setup** tab do not check the **Wait and return for exit code** box

If you want to debug change from /c to /k to leave the command window open.The archive comment should look something like this.

```
;The comment below contains SFX script commands
Setup="%comspec%" /c del "%sfxname%"
Silent=2
Overwrite=1
```

Available variables can be displayed at the command line after using /k

```
E:\New folder>SET SFX
sfxcmd="E:\New folder\ReadMe.exe"
sfxname=E:\New folder\ReadMe.exe
sfxpar=
sfxstime=2020-11-13-16-45-37-025
```